# Intellij is erroring when reading my build.gradle.kts file

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-kotlin-dsl

The red notification bar at the top says: `/org/gradle/tooling/BuildException (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /org/gradle/tooling/BuildException`. I can run a gradle refresh successfully, I can run the project successfully, but I cannot get that error to go away. I think my project is actually running fine, intellij just can't properly interpret the `build.gradle.kts` file for whatever reason. Does anybody know what to do? I included an image. Clicking on the red bar does nothing. I can find no more information about the error message anywhere. I'm running the latest intellij EDU.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Deleting the entire `.idea` as suggested Luxus would work, but would also be a little bit too extreme.

The problem comes from a misconfigured `.idea/workspace.xml`, try to find your the part which look like this in the `workspace.xml` file :

```
  <component name="StandaloneScriptsStorage">
    <option name="files">
      <set>
        <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$/your_module/build.gradle.kts" />
      </set>
    </option>
  </component>
```

You'll have to delete the whole `<component/>` tag, and maybe restart your idea to get rid of the issue.

Answer (score 5):

just delete `.idea` folder and restart IntelliJ.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-20903. Try to update your gradle version.

Comment: It definitely looks like that. However, I tried changing gradle versions several times with both the gradle wrapper and gradle itself. The error persists. FWIW, I also had IntelliJ set up to use the project wrapper. I tried pointing it at the gradle installed by homebrew and still had the error

Comment: Please, file an issue https://kotl.in/issue

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error too.

Step-1: I deleted the `.idea` file

[image]

Step-2: Then, when I did the 'Invalidate Caches' operation, the problem was resolved.

[image]